# How to reduce 'speed' of a rigidbody without changing the distance it has to cover?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am moving a rigidbody using `rb.AddForce(force,ForceMode.Impulse)` where force is the target position the rigidbody have to reach.

Now the speed it goes directly depends on the distance it has to cover.

Let's say the time taken to reach the target position is 3sec. I need the rigidbody to cover the same target pos in 5sec.

- I dont want to change the timescale as it affects my gameflow
- On Changing the velocity of rigidbody it fails to reach the target position

Comment: Do you want your rigid body to move to a specific target with constant speed?

Comment: _"Let's say the time taken to reach the target position is 3sec. I need the rigidbody to cover the same target pos in 5sec"_ - huh?

Comment: yes with a constant speed

Comment: There are a lot of good answers here that explain your problem. Maybe you should pick one so the bounty doesn't go to waste

Answer (score 1):

Some basic physics/math:

```
velocity = change-in-position / travel-time
force = mass * change-in-velocity / acceleration-time
```

For ease, we're going to call `change-in-position` as `distance`, and `change-in-velocity/acceleration-time` as `acceleration`

Now, since the `acceleration-time` component is effectively zero because you're using Impulse, we're going to remove it from the equation (in math terms, we set it at '1')

```
force = mass * change-in-velocity
```

Assuming your object starts at zero velocity, we can simplify `change-in-velocity` to just `velocity`

```
force = mass * velocity

force = mass * distance / travel-time
```

To bring that back into Unity code:

```
var mass = rb.mass;
var distance = destination.position - transform.position;
var travelTime = 5f; // seconds

var force = mass * distance / travelTime;

rb.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Note that this assumes a frictionless transfer and constant velocity.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts.
The problem here is,
var force = mass * distance / travelTime;
for the force, we are dividing the distance by time so it basically reduces the distance that have to be travelled by the rigidbody.
For me it have to travel the destination, only the travel time should vary

Comment: @bolov 
Let me explain the above with an example,

    rb.position = Vector3(0f,0f,0f);
Destination.position = Vector3(0f,0f,20f);
rb.mass = 1f;

var mass = rb.mass; 
//mass= 1;
var distance = destination.position - transform.position;
//distance = Vector3(0f,0f,20f);
var travelTime = 5f; // seconds

var force = mass * distance / travelTime;
//force = Vector3(0f,0f,4f);

rb.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Impulse);

Now the rigidbody moves to the position of Vector3(0f,0f,4f), but its destination is nvector3(0f,0f,20f)

Comment: @Nijanthan It sounds like you've got friction and will need to add extra force to counter the friction-based deceleration (which is beyond what I'm willing to dive into here)... Or make the rb ```kinematic``` and move it yourself.  Sorry I couldn't help more.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore gravity, this code solves the problem, here I changed the drag according to weight and distance, it may be a little bit away from the destination at the end, the reason should be higher drag friction.

```cs
public void ForceToTarget(Transform target, float time = 1f)
{
    var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    
    var vector = target.position - transform.position;

    var distance = vector.magnitude;
    
    rb.drag = distance/time;

    rb.AddForce(vector*rb.mass*distance/time, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want precise control over your speed, then stop using `ForceMode.Impulse` because other physics effects like drag will make your answers wrong. Instead, just set the speed yourself. You can do this with a `Coroutine` to control timing and `ForceMode.VelocityChange` to control the speed. Basically, just look at where you are, where the target is, how much time is left, and apply the speed directly.

```
private bool canMove = true;
public void MoveTo(Vector3 targetPosition, float targetTime)
{
    if(canMove)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveToCoroutine(targetPosition,targetTime));
    }
}
private IEnumerator MoveToCoroutine(Vector3 targetPosition, float time)
{
    canMove = false;
    while(time > 0)
    {
        var positionDelta = transform.position - targetPosition;
        var targetSpeed = positionDelta / time;
        var speedDelta = targetSpeed - rb.velocity;
        rb.AddForce(speedDelta , ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        yield return null;
        time -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    // Bring the object to a stop before fully releasing the coroutine
    rb.AddForce(-rb.velocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    canMove = true;
}
```

I wrote this here into the text editor, no IDE and haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure this'll do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the target position as-is then larger vectors will cause larger force to be applied than smaller vectors. Similarly, if using a direction vector as-is then as the rb gets closer to the target the magnitute of the vector gets smaller and thus less force is applied.

To get a constant speed use the direction to the target and [Normalise](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Normalize.html) it instead. Regardless of the distance the direction vector will always have a magnitude of 1 so you can multiply it by any value to accurately control the speed of the object:

```
Rigidbody rb;
public Transform target;
public float dist;
public float speed = 2f; // or whatever
public float targetDistance = 40f; // or whatever

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    StartCoroutine("IMove");
}

IEnumerator IMove()
{

    dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);

    while (dist > targetDistance)
    {
        dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.Normalize(target.position - transform.position) * speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too much into the physics and maths, if you want it to travel slower but the same distance you need to reduce the gravity on it and the initial force.
Note in this example I am assuming the weight is 1 to make the calculation a bit easier for force.

```
public class TrevelSpeedAdjusted
{
    public float speedFactor = 1;

    void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        // Reduce the gravity on the object
        rb.AddForce(-Physics.gravity * rigidbody.mass * (1 - speedFactor));
    }

    public float AddAdjustedForce(Vector3 force, ForceMode forceMode)
    {
        rb.AddForce(force * speedFactor, forceMode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can try DoTween package to do this pretty easily and its very convenient to use a package instead of using Unity's inbuilt system.
With doTween use this:
DOMove(Vector3 to, float duration, bool snapping) condition to tween your physics Gameobject to a given target position in the duration you require.

Here's documentation you can refer to if you want: http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php

Let me give you an example:

1. Install the doTween Package. http://dotween.demigiant.com/download
2. Import it to unity.
3. Go to your script where you want to achieve the functionality you mentioned on your question and add this header "using DG.Tweening".
4. Now get access of your RigidBody.
   For Example Lets say: I have a cube gameobject with rigidbidy and this script attached.
   The Cube Initial Position is at 0,0,0.

And I want it to move to 5,5,5 in 3 seconds or 5 seconds as per your questions request. And lets say I want this to happen when I click SpaceBar on keyboard.

So I would simply do.

```
Rigidbody rb;
void Start()
{
rb= GetComponent<Rigibody>();
}

void Update()
{
if(Input.GetButtonDown(Keycode.Space))
{
MoveCube(new Vector3(5,5,5),5);
}
}

void MoveCube(Vector3 inTargetPosition , float durationToReachTheTarget)
{
//What this line does is first take in the target position you want your physics object to reach as it first parameter, Then takes in the duration in which you want it to reach there.
rb.DoMove(inTargetPosition,durationToReachTheTarget);
}
```

This should help you. But remember this is only if you okay with adding an extra package. Personally this package is very good and I would recommend you this.